# One Select from multiple different databases

Tags: php, arrays

Hello everyone I am trying to get data from multiple databases by one select which i would like to sort and apply conditions on

I have database connects saved in my primary database like this

```
$GLOBALS['connects'] = array();
$GLOBALS['prefixes'] = array();
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shops ORDER BY ordering ASC",$connect);
while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $password = simple_decrypt($data['password']);
    $GLOBALS['connects'][$data['database']] = mysql_connect($data['host'],$data['user'],$password) or die ('bad data');
    $GLOBALS['prefixes'][$data['database']] = $data['prefix']; 
    mysql_select_db($data['database'], $GLOBALS['connects'][$data['database']]) or die ('bad select');  
}
```

Then i make query from global array variable

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM ';
$limit = count($GLOBALS['connects']);
$i = 0;
foreach($GLOBALS['connects'] as $key => $val){
    if(($i+1)==$limit){
        $query .= $key.'.'.$GLOBALS['prefixes'][$key].'orders';
    } else {
        $query .= $key.'.'.$GLOBALS['prefixes'][$key].'orders, ';
    } 
    $i++;  
}
```

The result is

```
"SELECT * FROM shop1.pr_orders, shop2.pl_orders, shop3.ps_orders, shop4.pt_orders"
```

now i would like to make it work also add WHERE condition and ORDER BY

right now it should show every order but instead it returns false

HINT:

**lets pretend chosen tables from databases have NOTHING in common**

Answer (score 0):

lets say that `Table1` is on `Database1` and `Table2` in `Database2` and you want to `join` them in a single `SELECT` do this :

```
Select * FROM Database1.Table1 JOIN Database2.Table2 ON Table1.Id=Table2.Id
```

Comment: they have nothing in common they are completely different they have only similar structure mostly.

Comment: i just answerd the qustion : "One Select from multiple databases"

Answer (score 0):

Your constructed SELECT statement can only work if the tables reside in different databases on the same MySQL server (the same host) and the connected user has access rights to all of them.

But as I understand, You are trying to SELECT from tables which reside in different MySQL servers. Then things goes more complicated - there are discussions about that:

- [Join tables from two different server - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114197/join-tables-from-two-different-server)
- [MySQL Cross Server Select Query - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810349/mysql-cross-server-select-query)

Another approach is to separately connect to each server, SELECT records from the tables and then merge by hand results in PHP - but I am not sure it is that you want.