# Join together Two diffrent Database Tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I want to join two diffrent database tables when i compared with common field (ID).The following code i was wriiten on my website but it shows an error

My code :

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username1", "password1", "databse1");
$conn1 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username2", "password2", "database2");
$result = '';
$query = "SELECT * FROM database1.table1,database2.table1  where 

database1.table1.id=database2.table1.id ";

$sql = mysqli_query($conn,$query);


$result .='
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
<th width="20%">ID</th>
<th width="10%">Qty</th>
</tr>';
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $result .='
        <tr>
        <td>'.$row["id"].'</td>
        <td>'.$row["qty"].'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
else
{
    $result .='
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5">No Item Found</td>
    </tr>';
}
$result .='</table>';
echo $result;
```

Error Messages :

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Please assist and help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try below query

```
select table1.*,table2.* from table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id
```

For further reading about `MYSQL JOINS` please check here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

**EDIT**
query isn't working because there is a error in your query, you have created two connection strings `$conn` and `$conn1` and using only 1, you dont need two different connection strings, give `username1` permission of both the databases `database1` and `database2` and remove `$conn1` only use `$conn`

if you are using any local server like `WAMP,XAMPP` etc then the `root` user have access to all the databases, if you are on `cpanel` then follow these steps to add user-database privileges: http://www.thehostingnews.com/how-to-grant-mysql-privileges-in-cpanel.html

**EDIT 2** as per the OP both the databases are on different server there can be some different possible solutions already answered before can be checked from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11114197/join-tables-from-two-different-server) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810349/mysql-cross-server-select-query)

Another possible solutions

1) You can create a temporary table on `database2` and insert the data from `database1` to `database2's` temporary table and **use JOIN query at `database2` only**

2) OR else you can use two different queries, first will fetch id from database1's table and using that id fire another query to database2's table

**EDIT 3 (edited code as per my #2nd suggestion)**

```
$conn   = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username1", "password1", "databse1");
$conn1  = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username2", "password2", "database2");
$result = '';
$query  = "SELECT * FROM database1.table1";
$sql    = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$result .='
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
<th width="20%">ID</th>
<th width="10%">Qty</th>
</tr>';
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0)
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        $query1 = "SELECT * FROM database2.table1 where table1.id = " . $row['id'];
        $sql1   = mysqli_query($conn1, $query1);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($sql1) > 0)
        {
            while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1))
            {
                $result .='<tr>
                            <td>' . $row1["id"] . '</td>
                            <td>' . $row1["qty"] . '</td>
                       </tr>';
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    $result .='
    <tr>
    <td colspan="5">No Item Found</td>
    </tr>';
}
$result .='</table>';
echo $result;
```

Comment: hi i tried "LEFT JOIN" now also the same error code comes again thanks

Comment: how to give username1 permission to access databse2 ? may be it was assigned only database1

Comment: okay thanks for your information but my problem was that both databases having different Cpanel (both are different websites) but running along the same server. so i don't know how can assign all cpanels  create and access  the same username and password

Comment: hi thank you so much but i really confuse that your sentence "first will fetch id from database1's table and using that id fire another query to database2's table" how can fetch the values to compare another query if u don't mine please provide anything query examples

Comment: okay thank you very much :)