# Laravel - Using multi connection in single query

Tags: laravel

I have use multiple database in my project. But is that possible to use multiple connection in single query in laravel? This is my connection config.

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],

    'mysql_pdd' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_PDD_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PDD_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_PDD_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_PDD_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PDD_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

I want to join a tabel in my `mysql` connection to `mysql_pdd` table. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
Yes, you can but for that you need to put condition, when you want to connect 'mysql' and when 'msql_pdd'.

if (mysql_connection){
 $mysql =DB:: reconnect('mysql');
}else if(mysql_pdd_connection){
 $mysql_pdd =DB:: reconnect('mysql_pdd');
}
```

Using $mysql & $mysql_pdd you can perform joins as well by code not by query.

Comment: Reference link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810349/mysql-cross-server-select-query/1546339#1546339