# Mysql query to fetch data from two databases of two different host

Tags: mysql, sql, join

A query or stored procedure to get data from two databases.
First get data from school database which is in host1

```
USE school;
SELECT id FROM student WHERE marks > 80;
```

With the result of first query from host2, admin database

```
Use admin;
SELECT * FROM student_details WHERE id IN (result from first db)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  admin.student_details sd 
WHERE sd.id IN 
  (SELECT 
    s.id 
  FROM
    school.student s 
  WHERE s.marks > 80)
```

It would be a lot better if you provided some of the sample table, data and your required output

Comment: Sorry its actually database from two different host

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/810349/mysql-cross-server-select-query)